# Using fabric.js free drawing, is there a way to paint over only certain fabric.Objects?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am developing a drawing application where the goal is to allow people to draw on images. I have a working "eraser" which is essentially a duplicate of the original image painted over top of all layers via using a `fabric.PatternBrush()`.

The issue I have with it is that if someone decides to use the eraser multiple times, then while zooming in/out on the image using `staticCanvas.zoomToPoint()`, each duplicate image from each eraser needs to be transformed, causing very serious lag.

So, is there some way that I could just use some `globalCompositeOperation` and a white PencilBrush to fix this problem, allowing the eraser to erase all path layers and no image layers?... or something of the sort.

**EDIT**

I fixed the issue by creating the pattern outside of the getPatternSrc function, and not using getPatternSrc at all. I instead used PatternBrush.source = HTMLCanvasElement. This allows the original image to be a single pattern that does not need to be regenerated for every single transform.

Another issue is that I am using typescript and the default d.ts file (and online documentation) does not show PatternBrush.source as a property that you can set.

I was originally doing something like this (source for using `getPatternSrc` from http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing) ...

```js
    var eraser = new fabric.PatternBrush(canvas);
    eraser.getPatternSrc = function() {
    let image = document.getElementById('originalImage') as HTMLImageElement,
        patternCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        { naturalWidth: width, naturalHeight: height } = image;
        patternCanvas.width = width;
        patternCanvas.height = height;
        let ctx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
        let pattern = ctx.createPattern(image, 'no-repeat') as CanvasPattern;
        ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        return patternCanvas;
    };
```

When I should have actually done this...

```js
    let eraser = new fabric.PatternBrush(canvas);
    let image = document.getElementById('originalImage') as HTMLImageElement,
        patternCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        { naturalWidth: width, naturalHeight: height } = image;
        patternCanvas.width = width;
        patternCanvas.height = height;
        let ctx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
        let pattern = ctx.createPattern(image, 'no-repeat') as CanvasPattern;
        ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    eraser.source = patternCanvas; // main solution & difference
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush = eraser;
```

Unfortunately there was 0 documentation for this issue.